# WinstonJS custom levels

Tags: node.js, winston

So I wanted to add two levels to my logger. But it is not logging, I have no idea why.. Here is my setup. Any ideas?

```
// setup
var logLevels = {
    levels: {
        trace: 0,
        debug: 1,
        info: 2,
        warn: 3,
        error: 4,
        critical: 5
    }
};

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    levels: logLevels.levels,
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
});

// test
console.info('----------------------');
logger.trace('trace');
logger.debug('debug');
logger.info('info');
logger.warn('warn');
logger.error('error');
logger.critical('critical');
console.info('----------------------');
```

Output:

```
----------------------
debug: debug
trace: trace
info: info
----------------------
```

Comment: It's also weird that the `debug` line was printed before the `trace` line

Comment: @yarons sometimes it gets printed after the second `----------------------`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[winston Logging levels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#logging-levels)

First problem here, Each level is given a specific integer priority. By default, its

```
{ error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, verbose: 3, debug: 4, silly: 5 }
```

So less is more important.

Second, you must specify `level` to each transport. In your case, you must set level to critical to show all messages.

> winston allows you to define a level property on each transport which specifies the maximum level of messages that a transport should log.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    levels: logLevels.levels,
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({level: 'critical'})
    ]
});
```